# Can mvvmcross be used without dependency on Xamarin?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvmcross

Being familiar with mvvmlight, I'm now starting to look into using mvvmcross instead given the nice ability to use it with Xamarin to eventually also support my code on ios and android.  However, I'm not there yet and would like to avoid taking a dependency on xamarin as long as I'm not actively targetting platforms other than WP8.1 and Win8.1.

Question: can mvvmcross be used without dependency on xamarin?  (From my research so far my understanding is that mvvmcross is closely linked to usage with xamarin; even to the extent they share libraries?  Would love to understand to what extent there's a hard dependency.)

As an alternative approach is there anyone successful in using mvvmlight for cross platform dev?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you try it? Are any of the dependencies when you're using windows a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can - the core of MvvmCross is PCL - it's **portable**.

Xamarin is used only for Xam.Android, Xam.iOS and Xam.Mac - you can use WP, WinRT, WPF, MonoMac,  Unity, etc without any Xamarin products.